# Batch Renaming Files in AppleScript, Only Changes Names of Every Other File

Tags: applescript

I have exactly 11 files. These are named 1.jpg, 2.jpg through to 11.jpg. I've come up with the following that half works.

The problem however is that only half the files are processed. Specifically only the odd numbered files are processed ie every second file is skipped. Any thoughts?

I've noted this person had a similar problem when renaming folders, however I am not knowledgeable enough to apply it to my scenario. [Batch Renaming Folders in AppleScript, Will Only Change Names of Every Other Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476702/batch-renaming-folders-in-applescript-will-only-change-names-of-every-other-fol)

```
display dialog "Person ID number. (numerals only)?" default answer ""
tell application "Finder"
set personid to text returned of result
set home_path to home as text
set file1name to "_front"
set file2name to "_prof"
set file3name to "_neck"
set file4name to "_no_phon"
set file5name to "_phon"
set file6name to "_max"
set file7name to "_prof_max"
set file8name to "_relax"
set file9name to "_prof_relax"
set file10name to "_depress_no_phon"
set file11name to "_depress_phon"

tell folder (home_path & "Downloads:sagicphotos")
    set name of file 1 to "PRN" & personid & file1name & "." & name extension of file 1
    set name of file 2 to "PRN" & personid & file2name & "." & name extension of file 2
    set name of file 3 to "PRN" & personid & file3name & "." & name extension of file 3
    set name of file 4 to "PRN" & personid & file4name & "." & name extension of file 4
    set name of file 5 to "PRN" & personid & file5name & "." & name extension of file 5
    set name of file 6 to "PRN" & personid & file6name & "." & name extension of file 6
    set name of file 7 to "PRN" & personid & file7name & "." & name extension of file 7
    set name of file 8 to "PRN" & personid & file8name & "." & name extension of file 8
    set name of file 9 to "PRN" & personid & file9name & "." & name extension of file 9
    set name of file 10 to "PRN" & personid & file10name & "." & name extension of file 10
    set name of file 11 to "PRN" & personid & file11name & "." & name extension of file 11
end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

When you rename the files, their order changes, so some files never get renamed. Just get a list of the files before renaming them:

```
set personid to "1234"

set filenames to paragraphs of "_front
_prof
_neck
_no_phon
_phon
_max
_prof_max
_relax
_prof_relax
_depress_no_phon
_depress_phon"

set filelist to paragraphs of (do shell script "cd ~/Downloads/sagicphotos; ls | sort -n")
tell application "Finder"
    set i to 1
    repeat with f in filelist
        tell file ((home as text) & "Downloads:sagicphotos:" & f)
            set name to "PRN" & personid & item i of filenames & "." & name extension
        end tell
        set i to i + 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Or using a shell script:

```
personid=1234

filenames=(_front
_prof
_neck
_no_phon
_phon
_max
_prof_max
_relax
_prof_relax
_depress_no_phon
_depress_phon)

cd ~/Downloads/sagicphotos
for f in $(ls | sort -n); do
  mv $f PRN$personid${filenames[i++]}.${f##*.}
done
```

Comment: The one problem I see with this is the order of the "filenames" and the order of the files i.e 1,2,3,4… will not match. file 10 will for example be name with _prof.

Comment: Very nice, ls to the rescue. I always forget about that little gem. knew there was a better way than my tangle.

Answer (score 0):

A slight change to user:495470 answer.

As I noted in the comments. the filenames" and the order of the files i.e 1,2,3,4… will not match if you do not take into account the sort order of the file list returned and the order of you file name list.

```
set theHomeF to ((path to home folder) & "Desktop:test:test1" as text) as alias
set personid to "1234"
set filenames to paragraphs of "_front
_prof
_neck
_no_phon
_phon
_max
_prof_max
_relax
_prof_relax
_depress_no_phon
_depress_phon"

tell application "Finder"
    set file_namesList to ""
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"
"}
    set thefiles to files of theHomeF

    set theNames to (name of files of theHomeF)

    set file_namesList to text items of theNames as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
    set file_namesList to paragraphs of (do shell script " echo  " & quoted form of file_namesList & "|sort -n")
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in file_namesList
        set this_item to item i of file_namesList
        set thisFile to (some file of theHomeF whose name is this_item)
        set name of thisFile to "PRN" & personid & item i of filenames & "." & name extension of thisFile
    end repeat
end tell
```

Note the line set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"
"}   has a **\n**  ( new line between the quotes)

I am sure there is a better way of doing this, But as they say time is money…